# All three thermodynamic terms being variable

Tags: thermodynamics, work, adiabatic

In preliminary thermodynamics, I learned about 4 special cases where at least one thermodynamic term is constant like isobaric, adiabatic, isochoric process. But how to evaluate the work, change in internal energy and enthalpy if $P,V,T,Q$ are all variable?

> [image: 1]

For instance here a system is being cycled from T1 to T2 to T3 and all the way to T1 again. Here, the system can exchange heat. From T2 to T3 the process is neither of the four (adiabatic, isochoric....). How I can determine $\text{d}U$, $\text{d}Q$ and $\text{d}W$ here?

Comment: For an ideal gas, U is independent of V, and depends only on T.

Answer (score 0):

Use w = P dV, which is easily integrated for the simple function you show, to obtain W. U is conserved, so you can use any convenient path between the two points. Q is then the difference between U and W. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> From T2 to T3 the process is neither of the four(adiabatic,
> isochoric....). How I can determine dU, dQ and dW here

WORK ($W_{A-C}$):

For any process, the work done during the expansion can be calculated from the equation

$$W=\int_{V_{1}}^{V_{2}}P_{ext}(V)dV$$

or in your case

$$W_{A-C}=\int_{V_{A}}^{V_{C}}P(V)dV$$

Where $P_{ext}(V)$ is the external pressure as a function of the volume of the gas. In this example you can determine the pressure as a function of volume graphically applying the general form $y=mx+b$.

Since the work done for any process is the area under the process path, in this example the area under the path A-C can be easily determined graphically as the the sum of the area enclosed by all three processes (the area of the triangle), plus the area under the isobaric process C-B. The net positive work done is the area of the triangle alone.

CHANGE IN INTERNAL ENERGY ($\Delta U_{A-C}$):

In the case of ideal gas behavior its change in internal energy is a function of temperature only according to (for 1 mole of gas).

$$\Delta U_{A-C}=c_{V}\Delta T=c_{V}(T_{3}-T_{2})$$

Where $c_{V}$ is the molar specific heat of the gas.

The temperatures $T_3$ and $T_2$ can be determined by applying the ideal gas law to equilibrium states A and C for one mole of gas since you know, from the graph, the pressure and volume at those states.

HEAT ($Q_{A-C})$

Given the calculations of work and change in internal energy, you can determine the heat transferred by applying the first law

$$\Delta U_{A-C}=Q_{A-C}-W_{A-C}$$

Hope this helps.